# Jupyter Notebook over 100 MB even after clearing all output

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a Jupyter Notebook that I wish to upload to GitHub. However, even after clearing all output, it's still larger than 100 MB. Stranger still, I created a duplicate and deleted everything in it, yet the duplicate still turned out to have the same size! I tried [`nbstripout`](https://pypi.org/project/nbstripout/), which didn't help, either.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to "purge" a Jupyter Notebook so that it's significantly smaller? Thank you so much!